# php preg_split last occurrence of character

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Looking for some help!

I need to split a string at the last occurrence of a space...

e.g. "Great Neck NY" I need to split it so I have "Great Neck" and "NY"

I haven't had a problem using preg_split with basic stuff but I'm stumped trying to figure out how to tell it only to split at the last occurrence! Any help would be appreciated!

Mike

Comment: If you run Windows, and you're not using it already, you should grab regex-coach to easily test/build your regex's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
preg_split('/\s+(?=\S+$)/', $str)
```

Now the string will be split at `\s+` (whitespace characters) only if `(?=\S+$)` would match from this point on. And `\S+$` matches non-whitespace characters immediately at the end of the string.

Comment: +1 Nice one! Been looking for something like this myself for a long time too.